# Status Meter Gauge in Oracle Apex displaying invalid data when value is 0

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a status meter gauge in my Oracle Apex application. It executes a query to retrieve the maximum value, minimum value and the label. In situations when there are no records to retrieve, then the maximum value is returned as 0. Upon displaying the maximum value as the value of the status meter gauge it is displaying as invalid data.

The maximum value is 0, minimum value is 0 and the status meter gauge is displaying invalid data.

[image]

Query:

```
SELECT
COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_COUNT,
0 AS MINIMUM_VALUE,
'Inactive' AS MY_LABEL
FROM TN_DETAILS
WHERE STATUS = 'Inactive';
```

**What I tried:** If the maximum value is 0 I want 0 to be displayed in the status meter gauge. I have tried to remove the minimum value of the status meter gauge as the maximum and maximum value cannot be the same. But it did not work.

I need status meter gauge to display 0 if the maximum value is 0.